# Al usar dotenv, el programa no reconoce la función require, y me manda a hacer import

Tags: nodejs

Estoy haciendo una prueba, con el desarrollo de un sitio web desde Node con vista en PUG.
Cuando intento pasar a la etapa del *deployment*, utilizo dotenv para la preparación de las variables de entorno para luego cargarlas en el servidor (HEROKU, por dar un ejemplo).
Hago el desarrollo de mi archivo (`variables.env`), y cuando voy a hacer la configuración de la conexión de las variables de entorno con el archivo de la base de datos, desarrollo en siguiente código

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
require('dotenv').config( {path: 'variables.env'});


const db  = new Sequelize(process.env.BD_NOMBRE, process.env.BD_USER, process.env.BD_PASS, {
    host: process.env.BD_HOST,
    port: process.env.BD_PORT,
    dialect:'mysql',
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    },
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000
    },
    operatorAliases: false
});

export default db;
```

El `package.json` esta configurado de forma modular, y el error que me aparece es el siguiente, cuando hago la compilación y corrida del archivo.

```
> ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\xampp2\htdocs\agenciaviajesNode\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/xampp2/htdocs/agenciaviajesNode/config/db.js:3:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:169:25)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... 
>
```

Necesito tener la variable `db` porque esta conectada con todos los archivos, de manera de no modificar el resto de las carpetas para modificar el código.
Alguno por favor me podría indicar cual es el error allí?

Saludos

Comment: Si usas ES Module, ¿para qué usar `require`?. Basta con que cambias tu importación: `import { config } from "dotenv";`, y luego simplemente llamas a la función: `config({path: 'variables.env'});`. Saludos

Comment: Incorpora el modulo con: npm i dotenv. Luego llamar con: const dotenv = require('dotenv'); Por último configuras: dotenv.config({ path: './variables.env' });

Comment: @WilsonPT ese no es el problema, el problema es que está usando módulos ES6 que no son compatibles con `require`. Tu sugerencia es bienvenida, pero no aplica en este caso. Saludos